# ImportError - arch module python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the arch module in python. After installing it, I succesfully imported `arch_model` by executing `from arch import arch_model`.

However, I also need to use other functions, such as `ConstantMean`, as documented on the maintainers github [here](http://bashtage.github.io/arch/doc/univariate/mean.html#mean-models).

Yet, when I try to import it, it gives me the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ConstantMean' from 'arch'
> (C:\Users\frede\anaconda3\envs\earnings_risk\lib\site-packages\arch_*init*_.py)

When I check the functions available in the module via `dir(arch)` it also does not list `ConstantMean`, nor most of the other functions that should theoretically be available according to the documentation. What can be the reason for this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
from arch.univariate import ConstantMean
```